# A density lemma for families of sequences indexed by the unit interval

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, sequences-and-series

Suppose for every $x \in [0, 1]$, we have a subset $S_x$ of the natural numbers with asymptotic density $1$ such that if
$n \in S_x$, there is an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ (depending on $x$ and $n$) such that $n \in S_y$ for all $y \in U$.

**Question:**

For any $\varepsilon > 0$ can I find a subset $M$ of $[0, 1]$ with $\mu(M) > 1 - \varepsilon$, and a subset $K \subset \mathbb N$ of positive upper density satisfying the following condition?

- For all $x \in M$, there exists some $N > 0$ such that $K \cap [N, \infty)$ is a subset of $S_x \cap [N, \infty)$.

*A word on motivation:* This question arose in trying to prove [this
result](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/393685/almost-arzela-ascoli) on sequences of “almost equicontinuous” functions. The result as stated turns out to be false as shown by Mateusz Kwaśnicki in the comments and Iosif Pinelis in his answer, but I believe if this lemma is true, I can get a subsequence that converges in measure to *some* function $f$, not necessarily continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $S_x=\{n\colon \langle n!x\rangle>\frac 1n\}$, where $\langle \cdot\rangle$ is the fractional part of $\cdot$. Another way to think of this is you can (essentially uniquely) write a number as
$$
x=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{a_n(x)}{n!},
$$
where $a_n(x)\in\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$. This is the expansion of $x$ where the first digit is base 2, the next digit is base 3 etc. $S_x$ is the set of places where $x$ does not have a zero. Notice that if $x$ is chosen uniformly with respect to Lebesgue measure, then the random variables $a_n(x)$ are uniform and independent on $\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$. So we see that $S_x$ has full density for almost all $x$.

Now if $K$ is a subset of $\mathbb N$ of positive density, the probability that $a_n(x)\ne 0$ for each $n\in K$ is
$$
\prod_{n\in K}\frac{n-1}n=\prod_{n\in K}(1-\tfrac 1n).
$$
Since $K$ has positive density, that probability is 0.

In particular, for any $M$ of positive measure, any $K$ of full density and any $N$, $K\cap [N,\infty)$ still has positive density, so we may apply the above to $K\cap [N,\infty)$ to see that the set of $x$'s in $M$ where $K\subset S_x$ has measure 0.

Comment: Hmm I think there might be a big difference between $S_x$ having full density for almost all $x$, versus for every $x$ though. Do you think it matters?

Comment: @NateRiver : I just deleted my comment about redefining $S$ for the bad $x$’s. That violates the openness condition. I think I can see a way to get both, but there’s a little work needed.

Comment: Yes it does seem that the condition I gave (that $K$ is eventually equal to $S_x$) is too strong. Maybe I need a different lemma.